# Blank pages on ONE VS domain which an Apache restart fixes

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, apache, cloudflare

You can see the whole thread (which no-one from WP or anyone else) has been able to help me with here >

During the thread I actually updated my site checker plugin to include the output of free / disk swapped memory, free RAM, used RAM, PHP memory use at time of recording etc.

You can see that plugin (and tell me if anything is wrong with it) here >

http://wordpress.org/plugins/strictly-system-check/

The thread is here.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/blank-scree-due-to-memory-allocation-failure?replies=5#post-5807762

I am on a VPS with 2GB Ram, 4GB VM, behind Cloudflare, ban over 43% of traffic from .htaccess and network rules although I now think due to there not being a Cloudflare repair IP patch for Lenny Linux 5 (old machine I know - not got time to fix at moment) that a lot of these network rules are being ignored as they all come through as Cloudflare.

In VMIN the info says

**Kernel and CPU    Linux 2.6.32.9-rscloud on x86_64    CPU load averages   0.30 (1 min) 0.48 (5 mins) 0.79 (15 mins)
Running processes   146 Real memory 2.01 GB total, 956.26 MB used 
Virtual memory  4 GB total, 503.59 MB used 
Local disk space    74.81 GB total, 22.54 GB used 
Package updates All Virtualmin packages are up to date.**

The last post which happened when I checked my email at 6am this Sunday morning showed me an error report at 5.09 (runs at 7 past the hour).

Full report is at the bottom.

Hi

Right I just ran into the white screen of death again on my site.

Homepage with wp-debug ON said

Notice: attribute_escape is deprecated since version 2.8! Use esc_attr() instead. in /home/darkpolitricks/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3078

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/darkpolitricks/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:3078) in /home/darkpolitricks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-phase2.php on line 91

No fatal errors on homepage

when I went to wp-admin / wp-login.php I could login though.

So I turned the debug back on
No errors just warnings e.g

Notice: Undefined variable: cookies in /home/darkpolitricks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-phase1.php on line 660

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/darkpolitricks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-phase1.php:660) in /home/darkpolitricks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/easy-adsense-lite/EzTran.php on line 196

Notice: attribute_escape is deprecated since version 2.8! Use esc_attr() instead. in /home/darkpolitricks/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3078

Notice: register_sidebar_widget is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_sidebar_widget() instead. in /home/darkpolitricks/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3078

This is a theme my mate put together based on Carrington Blog I don't know if these warnings are important but they don't cause issues most of the time.

**No Errors or Fatal Errors could be seen in the back end.**

**At the same time note all my other sites on the same server were working fine.**

I tried my "bypass" cloudflare domain e.g rob.example.com but that didn't do anything.

As always a restart of Apache fixed this one site again.

Here is output I got during the time the homepage/front end was blank from the server.

I ran a TOP ignoring Zombie processes e.g top -i -H

Results
06:02:47 up 16 days,  3:05,  1 user,  load average: 1.12, 1.05, 1.14
Tasks: 136 total,   2 running, 134 sleeping,   0 stopped,   **0 zombie**
Cpu(s):  4.4%us,  1.8%sy,  0.0%ni, 49.0%id, 44.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.1%st
Mem:   2109548k total,  2015788k used,    93760k free,     9332k buffers
Swap:  4194296k total,   504124k used,  3690172k free,  1094764k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
20297 www-data  20   0  283m  47m  29m D    5  2.3   0:00.19 apache2
   75 root      20   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0   0:18.88 kblockd/0
 1901 root      20   0     0    0    0 D    0  0.0  13:19.73 flush-8:1
  679 mysql     20   0  656m 289m 2368 D    0 14.0   6:26.27 mysqld
20296 root      20   0 18888 1280  944 R    0  0.1   0:00.00 top

A free command

```
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
```

Mem:       2109548    1767116     342432          0       6376     920084
-/+ buffers/cache:     840656    1268892
Swap:      4194296     504092    3690204

This shows me that there wad memory about and not many apache processes.

I then got the results of my scheduled system report (which kicked it all off otherwise I wouldn't have know the site was down)

```
System Report: 2014-07-20 05:09:00

Initiating System Report...
Using Strictly System Check Version: 1.0.8
Initiating an HTTP request to http://www.example.com
The HTTP request to http://www.example.com took 1 second(s) to respond and returned a status code of 500
The specified search text <strong>read more</strong> could not be located within the HTTP response
The server is running under the user of www-data
<strong>The server load is currently 0.36
The server load is okay
Your available server memory is 2.00GB
Your current server memory usaage was 91.51%
Your available disk swap memory is 4GB
Your disk swap memory usage is 14.93%
MySQL DB Real Memory Size: 235.63MB
The PHP Memory usage at the time of the report was 1.25MB</strong>
MySQL has been running for: 16 days 2 hours 9 mins 40 secs
Total Connections: 605071 - Aborted: 0 - Connections Per Hour 1566
Total Queries: 33838003 - Queries / Per Hour 87626
Joins without indexes: 0 - Joins without indexes Per Hour 0
Total Reads: 5768028 (88%) - Total Writes 733689 (12%)
Initiating a check for corrupt tables and indexes
Table: wp_commentmeta does not need repairing
Table: wp_comments does not need repairing
Table: wp_links does not need repairing
Table: wp_options does not need repairing
Table: wp_postmeta does not need repairing
Table: wp_posts does not need repairing
Table: wp_term_relationships does not need repairing
Table: wp_term_taxonomy does not need repairing
Table: wp_terms does not need repairing
Table: wp_usermeta does not need repairing
Table: wp_users does not need repairing
Table: wp_wbz404_logs does not need repairing
Table: wp_wbz404_redirects does not need repairing
Table: wp_wpo_campaign does not need repairing
Table: wp_wpo_campaign_category does not need repairing
Table: wp_wpo_campaign_feed does not need repairing
Table: wp_wpo_campaign_post does not need repairing
Table: wp_wpo_campaign_word does not need repairing
Table: wp_wpo_log does not need repairing
No repairing of tables was required
Completed check for corrupt tables and indexes
The system is currently configured to accept a maximum of 25 database connections
At the time of reporting the database was running 1 query
The current database load is 4%
The database load is okay
The system is not set up to OPTIMIZE the tables or the server load of 0.36 was below the threshold for an OPTIMIZE of 15.
The system report concludes that the site is having problems and requires some immediate attention.

An email is being sent to me@example.com


Report Completed At 2014-07-20 05:09:00

Strictly Software Plugins for Wordpress
```

So this happens out of the blue and a restart of Apache fixes it always.

I am guessing due to security and the fact I am using www-data to init the call a blank screen of death cannot be fixed with a restart of apache automatically using shell_exec. Maybe I need a demon running on the server to do similar checks and then run it - horrible idea though - want to fix underlying problem.

Must BE some PHP script or service killing the system (only one - others work on same server)

Therefore I am at a loss.

The only errors in the log file for that time period were client denied (firewall blocks) e.g

[Sun Jul 20 04:36:12 2014] [error] [client 188.114.99.241] client denied by server configuration: /home/mysite/public_html/2013, referer: https://www.google.com/
[Sun Jul 20 05:16:46 2014] [error] [client 188.114.102.125] client denied by server configuration: /home/mysite/public_html/xmlrpc.php
[Sun Jul 20 05:31:56 2014] [error] [client 188.114.99.232] client denied by server configuration: /home/mysite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-o-matic/cache/4f002_http4.bp.blogspot.com-A81P4mnlJ2cUnv41979RKIAAAAAAABAU4AZk14sNBKBs329.jpg
[Sun Jul 20 05:56:49 2014] [error] [client 188.114.102.142] client denied by server configuration: /home/mysite/public_html/comments

188.114.102.142 is a cloudflare IP addresss.

As my box is old and I don't have the time there is not a Lenny patch from Cloudflare to get the IPS returned to their normal IPS in the files etc.

I do have the WP Clouflare plugin installed that does Akismet though (and just that I believe).

My report is scheduled to run at 7 past the hour. So I checked access logs.

Everything running fine

108.162.215.198 - - [20/Jul/2014:04:49:23 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 38027 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8" 0/927136
108.162.212.192 - - [20/Jul/2014:04:55:12 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 144 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" 0/348030
108.162.212.51 - - [20/Jul/2014:04:55:13 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 38030 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" 0/932853
108.162.221.68 - - [20/Jul/2014:04:55:19 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 325 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.0.19; aggregator:Spinn3r (Spinn3r 3.1); http://spinn3r.com/robot) Gecko/2010040121 Firefox/3.0.19" 0/26488
108.162.216.160 - - [20/Jul/2014:05:00:58 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 144 "-" "Feedfetcher-Google; (+http://www.google.com/feedfetcher.html; 1 subscribers; feed-id=16799781611961306038)" 0/805170
173.245.55.70 - - [20/Jul/2014:05:01:00 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 20 "-" "Feedfetcher-Google; (+http://www.google.com/feedfetcher.html; 1 subscribers; feed-id=16799781611961306038)" 1/1210085

then this request which was given a 403 forbidden

108.162.221.68 - - [20/Jul/2014:04:55:19 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 325 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.0.19; aggregator:Spinn3r (Spinn3r 3.1); http://spinn3r.com/robot) Gecko/2010040121 Firefox/3.0.19" 0/26488

then all 500 status codes to the homepage until I rebooted

108.162.216.160 - - [20/Jul/2014:05:00:58 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 144 "-" "Feedfetcher-Google; (+http://www.google.com/feedfetcher.html; 1 subscribers; feed-id=16799781611961306038)" 0/805170
173.245.55.70 - - [20/Jul/2014:05:01:00 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 20 "-" "Feedfetcher-Google; (+http://www.google.com/feedfetcher.html; 1 subscribers; feed-id=16799781611961306038)" 1/1210085
173.245.55.70 - - [20/Jul/2014:05:02:01 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 20 "-" "Feedfetcher-Google; (+http://www.google.com/feedfetcher.html; 1 subscribers; feed-id=16799781611961306038)" 1/1188995
173.245.55.70 - - [20/Jul/2014:05:03:03 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 20 "-" "Feedfetcher-Google; (+http://www.google.com/feedfetcher.html; 1 subscribers; feed-id=16799781611961306038)" 1/1155199
173.245.55.70 - - [20/Jul/2014:05:04:04 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 20 "-" "Feedfetcher-Google; (+http://www.google.com/feedfetcher.html; 1 subscribers; feed-id=16799781611961306038)" 1/1133494
173.245.54.199 - - [20/Jul/2014:05:06:17 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.59.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.10" 1/1156219
108.162.245.42 - - [20/Jul/2014:05:07:00 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)" 1/1207917
173.245.55.163 - - [20/Jul/2014:05:07:01 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.75 Safari/537.1" 1/1190563
173.245.55.70 - - [20/Jul/2014:05:08:20 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 20 "-" "Feedfetcher-Google; (+http://www.google.com/feedfetcher.html; 1 subscribers; feed-id=16675227896629445363)" 2/2765042

me restarting Apache

86.2.70.21 - - [20/Jul/2014:06:17:57 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0" 1/1176223

All 200's to the homepage OR 403s where i have banned in .htaccess the robot

141.101.99.192 - - [20/Jul/2014:06:19:41 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 38035 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36" 1/1087529
108.162.215.243 - - [20/Jul/2014:06:23:36 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 37137 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.1; Windows NT)" 4/4362257
108.162.215.243 - - [20/Jul/2014:06:23:39 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 37136 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.1; Windows NT)" 1/1161635
199.27.128.160 - - [20/Jul/2014:06:23:41 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 325 "http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.htm" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)" 0/26806
108.162.221.68 - - [20/Jul/2014:06:25:48 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 325 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.0.19; aggregator:Spinn3r (Spinn3r 3.1); http://spinn3r.com/robot) Gecko/2010040121 Firefox/3.0.19" 0/27637
108.162.222.160 - - [20/Jul/2014:06:28:06 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 322 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)" 0/25588
173.245.55.182 - - [20/Jul/2014:06:35:28 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 24073 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 Safari/9537.53" 2/2279796

time of my report

108.162.245.42 - - [20/Jul/2014:05:07:00 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)" 1/1207917
173.245.55.163 - - [20/Jul/2014:05:07:01 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.75 Safari/537.1" 1/1190563

However I did notice that this seemed to effect the homepage rather than other pages e.g requests to actual pages or posts were still having 200 status codes returned during this period of activity.

So maybe it is something to do with WP Super Cache and the home page?
Or cloudflare and the homepage?

Any help would be very much appreciated to get to the bottom of this.

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a CloudFlare issue (generally not the cause of a blank page). Does the behavior change if you pause CloudFlare? A blank page is generally going to be an issue on your server directly.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I think I just reduced the number of Max Connections down from the stupid default of 255 to something the system could manage e.g 12-18.

I wrote a BASH script that takes the available memory (2GB) on the box and deducts the size of the MySQL footprint before dividing it by the average Apache Process memory size.

This gave me a much smaller number of concurrent connections to allow but it meant that they were dealt with quicker rather than allowing a big build up of connections trying to consume lots of memory that wasn't there (causing disk swapping).

I also turned off some Apache caching modules on the server (Far too many places caching can be used on LAMP), banned any IE version under 7 as it seems a LOT of hackers/spammers use IE 6 (even 5.5) - probably due to the ancient age of the code the script kiddy has downloaded or to attack Intranets reliant on IE 6. No normal person should be using such ancient UA's in this day and age. This reduced a lot of traffic.

I also increased the crawl-delay value in my Robots.txt as I found BOTS were crawling far too frequently and if you are only posting 4 - 8 new articles a day you don't need BING/YSLURP to come and crawl your whole site constantly. It's a shame GoogleBOT doesn't support this but I used Webmaster tools to decrease their crawl rate.

I also implemented a delay in a plugin I wrote Strictly TweetBOT which can tweet out various messages to multiple accounts, or different messages to the same account based on the context of an article, words contained within it and so on. As I found that any tweet going out of the site would cause a [Twitter Rush](http://blog.strictly-software.com/2015/05/twitter-rush-rush-just-gets-bigger-and.html) that would instantly spawn up to a 100 hits to your site from people constantly analysing Twitter (for sites, hashtags, links etc). There are so many bandwidth wasters out there and social media BOTS that I just 403 most of them now.

Anyway I put a delay in of X seconds (customisable) between each Tweet sent out as well as an initial call to the article itself to ensure it get's cached by whatever WordPress caching system you are using (WP Super Cache / W3 Total etc) and then a delay of X seconds before the first Tweet is sent.

This is because otherwise you would send a Tweet and get 100 requests all hitting you at the same time which probably causes the caching system issues. Better to cache the page yourself in readiness for the rush.

There were probably some other tweaks I did as well such as implementing a lot of my own .htaccess rules to block XSS/SQL injection attacks and bad bots from visiting and locking down my login to a secret URL and sending anyone trying to go to /wp-admin to an FBI Cyber Crimes most wanted web site which seemed to reduce a lot of hack attempts.

I also (before WP did this as standard in their wp-db.php class that handles all DB connections), implemented a loop for DB calls that tested for the "MySQL Has Gone Away" error and if found, re-connected to the DB Server/Opened DB before re-attempting the query. I found that a lot of the time blank pages were coming up with little CPU usage coincided with batches of these errors in my log files.

I also hid OS, PHP, WP details from headers that crawlers could use to find weak sites and obviously locked my SSH port down to IP addresses I control to prevent attacks.